# How to specify custom timeout for bazel test

Tags: bazel

`bazel test` command uses default timeout of 75 seconds for tests tagged `size = small` in my setup (version 0.12.0) (while the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/test-encyclopedia.html) mentions this as 60 seconds)

Is there a way to supply a custom timeout say 10 seconds, on `bazel` command line, so that if a test hangs it is terminated quicker?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I hope I did not misread the question, but this really sounds like you're looking for `--test_timeout` option:

```
  --test_timeout
    (a single integer or comma-separated list of 4 integers; default: "-1")
    Override the default test timeout values for test timeouts (in secs). If a 
    single positive integer value is specified it will override all 
    categories.  If 4 comma-separated integers are specified, they will 
    override the timeouts for short, moderate, long and eternal (in that 
    order). In either form, a value of -1 tells blaze to use its default 
    timeouts for that category.
```

If you want to use the same option(s) every time, you can save yourself some typing by using [bazelrc](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#bazelrc).